# Understanding C String Concatenation

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

For an assesment in C i have to take two files with strings within them, and a string to concatenate them together e.g:

If file1 contains

```
Now is the

time for all

good men to

come to the aid of

the party.
```

and file2 contains:

```
alpha

beta

gamma
```

then the output from

```
scat XX file1 file2
```

(scat being the program name)

should be

```
Now is theXXalpha

time for allXXbeta

good men toXXgamma

come to the aid ofXX

the party.XX
```

and the output from

```
scat XX file2 file1
```

should be

```
alphaXXNow is the

betaXXtime for all

gammaXXgood men to

XXcome to the aid of

XXthe party.
```

In order to understand this i've been trying to play around with string concatenation trying to manually concat strings together.

My question is (A: how to i access individual lines of a file in c?) and B: if I manually input:

```
  char *str1 = "hello";

  char *str2 = "world";
```

how would i add these strings together without a predefined function. My thoughts initially were to use a for loop:

```
 for(str1; *str1 != '\0'; str1++)

     if(*str1 == '\0')

       *str1++ = *str2++;
```

my only issue is wouldn't this cause a seg fault due to memory access?

when i encounter a '\0' in a string..how can i extend this string? unless i just copy both strings into a new  char str3[200] ?

(all of the above is to try and help me understand how strings and string concat works, any assistance in learning this would be appreciated.)

Euden

Comment: Calling your program `scat` may cause unintended connotations with the quality of your implementation.

Comment: String handling in C is nasty business. If you truly want to handle lines of arbitrary, unbounded length, be prepared to write lots of loops and `malloc`s. `strncat` and `fgets` will be your main worker functions. The problem would be a **lot** simpler if you can assume that both files will fit into memory entirely.

Comment: You may consider to use standard strcat, strcpy if you can use predefined functions. strncat and strncpy are safer but do the same thing.

Comment: are you sure you are not allowed to use C++ ?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Comments on what you have at the moment: when you write `char *str1 = "hello";` you have a pointer to a non-modifiable literal. You need to declare `str1` to be modifiable memory if you want to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no need for string concatenation if the only goal is reading from two files, and writing to stdout, only a one-character buffer is sufficient, and a simple state machine will do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
int ch, state ;

if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argc=%d, should be > 3\n", argc);
        return 0;
        }

for (state = 0; state < 42;     ) {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
                fp1 = fopen (argv[2], "r"); if (!fp1) return 0;
                fp2 = fopen (argv[3], "r"); if (!fp2) { fclose (fp1); return 0;}
                state++;
        case 1:
                ch = fgetc(fp1);
                if (ch == EOF) state = 10;
                else if (ch == '\n') state =2;
                else putchar(ch);
                break;
        case 2:
                fputs( argv[1], stdout);
                state = 3;
        case 3:
                ch = fgetc(fp2);
                if (ch == EOF) state = 22;
                else if (ch == '\n') state =4;
                else putchar(ch);
                break;
        case 4:
                putchar(ch);
                state = 1;
                break;
        case 10: /* fp1 exhausted */
                ch = fgetc(fp2);
                if (ch == EOF) state = 30;
                else if (ch == '\n') state = 12;
                else {
                        fputs( argv[1], stdout );
                        putchar(ch);
                        state = 11;
                        }
                break;
        case 11:
                ch = fgetc(fp2);
                if (ch == EOF) state = 13;
                else if (ch == '\n') state = 12;
                else putchar(ch);
                break;
        case 12:
                putchar(ch);
                state = 10;
                break;
        case 13:
                putchar('\n');
                state = 30;
                break;
        case 20: /* fp2 exhausted */
                ch = fgetc(fp1);
                if (ch == EOF) state = 30;
                else if (ch == '\n') state = 21;
                else putchar(ch);
                break;
        case 21:
                fputs( argv[1], stdout);
                state = 22;
        case 22:
                putchar('\n');
                state = 20;
                break;
        case 30: /* both fp1+fp2 exhausted */

                fclose (fp1);
                fclose (fp2);
                state = 42;
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: don't try this at home.

Comment: this looks a lot more complex than what I am meant to achieve I think, the actual assesment requires I concatenate with the string provided. Although reading and printing them out to screen was suggessted by my professor rather than using a predefined function

Comment: Well, it was only intended as an illustration of how things *could* be.  Please note that it will also will work on input files with strings larger than available memory. A version with fgets() instead of fgetc() is also possible, needing approx half the number of states.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do it for you, but here are some tips/pitfalls.

1. Handle corner cases. What if the files don't have the same number of lines?
2. Unless you really have to support unlimited lines (ask your professor) I would suggest a buffer of 2048 characters for the input and 5000 for the output (2*2048 + concatenation string).
3. You'll want to read using `fgets` into the input buffers for both files, and then concatenate them with `strncat`.

Comment: Why concatenate with `strncat()`?  Why not concatenate them on the output with `printf("%s%s%s\n", line1, separator, line2);`, where I assume that the lines have the newline chopped off as they are read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That is a solution too, but `strncat` is more semantic.

Answer (score 0):

How you go about reading the lines from your input files should probably be based on what functions your professor has taught you or had you read about. Certainly not the best way to do it, but a simple way is to use fopen() to open the file, then getline() to read each line. This is simple but requires you to allocate excess buffer space (and risk a buffer overrun if you're not sure how much space you'll need). It also requires you to trim the \n from each line of input.

As to concatenating without using the built-in function, your proposed method may have the problem you fear. You need to know how much space you have available to write into and if you go beyond that, you're asking for trouble (and you will receive it). Creating a new buffer for the purpose of placing the output will keep you safe, but you suggest creating two new buffers; only one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need hints, review the source code behind Martin Broadhurst's *[Reading a Text File in C](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/textfile.html)* and the function [`strcat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcat.html). There are many places on the internet where source code for `strcat()` is available.