# Sideways conCATenate

Tags: c, file-io, text-files, separator

Hi I have recently been given a task in C.

The aim of the task is to read from two text files and output each line of each file side by side with a separator string in the middle of said lines.

Example:

file 1 contains:

```
green
blue
red
```

file 2 contains:

```
rain                                
sun
```

separator string = xx

output =

```
greenxxrain                                
bluexxsun                                  
redxx
```

I have managed to do this but was wondering if anyone else has any alternatives. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int f1, f2;
    FILE *file1, *file2;

    file1 = fopen("textone", "r"); //open file1 for reading.
    file2 = fopen("texttwo", "r"); //open file2 for reading.

    //if there are two files ready, proceed.
    if (file1 && file2){
        do{
            //read file1 until end of line or end of file is reached.
            while ((f1 = getc(file1)) != '\n' && f1!= EOF  ){
                //write character.
                putchar(f1);
            }
            //print separator string.
            printf("xx");   
            //read file2 until end of line or end of file is reached.
            while ((f2 = getc(file2)) != '\n' && f2!= EOF ){
                //write character.
                putchar(f2);
            }
            putchar('\n');    
        //do this until both files have reached their end.
        }while(f1 != EOF || f2 != EOF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555167/understanding-c-string-concatenation (for which I created a beautiful state machine ;-)

Comment: Look up the [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [`fgets(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) useful.  It can be used to read a whole line at once.  That said, it has downsides, too - you need to know how long the line is going to be, for example, or at least handle the case where the line is longer than your buffer.  Your implementation seems fine to me (except that you should call [`fclose(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose)).

Comment: would I be right in thinking to use fclose() after the main loop?

Comment: also the text files can be of variable length, I tried to use fgets() but couldn't think of a way to merge the lines together with the separator

Comment: Yes to the `fclose` question, and you don't *need* `fgets`, your implementation is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function to avoid the 'big' repetition in the `do { ... } while` loop:

```
static void read_and_echo_line(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        putchar(c);
}


...

    do
    {
        read_and_echo_line(file1);
        printf("xx");   
        read_and_echo_line(file2);
        putchar('\n');    
    } while (!feof(file1) || !feof(file2));
```

In this context, it is fairly reasonable to use `feof()` as shown (though it is not a function to use most of the time).  Alternatively:

```
static int read_and_echo_line(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        putchar(c);
    return(c);
}

...

    do
    {
        f1 = read_and_echo_line(file1);
        printf("xx");   
        f2 = read_and_echo_line(file2);
        putchar('\n');    
    } while (f1 != EOF || f2 != EOF);
```